# Calculation between fields in different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, select

I have two tables.

**table_1 :**

```
id,value1
2015,100
```

**table_2 :**

```
id,target
2015,200
```

I want to find the percentage of achievement : `table_1.value1/table_2.target=...%`.
How to create `SQL` scripts in Microsoft Access and Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the tables.

Assuming you mean per id:

```
SELECT table_1.id, value/target
FROM   table_1
JOIN   table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

ORACLE - to get the percent value with 2 decimal places (for example):

```
SELECT 
       table_1.id, 
       ROUND(table_1.value/table_2.target * 100, 2) percentage
FROM
       table_1,
       table_2
WHERE
       table_1.id = table_2.id
```

Comment: Should be using ANSI joins by now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be like this

```
SELECT table_1.id,table_1.value/table_2.target * 100 percentage
FROM   table_1 JOIN   table_2
ON table_1.id = table_2.id;
```